# Как объединить таблицы join,ошибка в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: May 20, 2020 at 07:33 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.24
-- PHP Version: 7.4.1
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
--
-- Database: `d_base`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `devices`
--
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `devices_atribut`
--
CREATE TABLE `devices_atribut` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `devices_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `Section` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip_adrerss` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `OS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Host_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CPU` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Dumping data for table `devices_atribut`
--
INSERT INTO `devices_atribut` (`id`, `devices_id`, `Name`, `Code`, `Username`, `Section`, `ip_adrerss`, `OS`, `Login`, `Host_Name`, `CPU`) VALUES
(9, NULL, 'dfgdfg', 'dfgdfgdf', 'dfgd', 'gdfg', '65656565', 'dfgdfg', 'dfgdfg', 'dgdfg', 'dfgdfgd');
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `devices_type`
--
CREATE TABLE `devices_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `devices_st_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Dumping data for table `devices_type`
--
INSERT INTO `devices_type` (`id`, `Name`, `devices_st_id`) VALUES
(37, 'dfgdgd', NULL),
(38, 'fdf', 47),
(39, 'fdf', 47);
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `statuses`
--
CREATE TABLE `statuses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Dumping data for table `statuses`
--
INSERT INTO `statuses` (`id`, `device_id`, `status_name`) VALUES
(39, NULL, 'use');
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `statuses_chekid`
--
CREATE TABLE `statuses_chekid` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Dumping data for table `statuses_chekid`
--
INSERT INTO `statuses_chekid` (`id`, `time`, `status_id`) VALUES
(24, '2020-05-14 00:00:00.000000', NULL);
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
--
-- Indexes for table `devices`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
--
-- Indexes for table `devices_atribut`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_atribut`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `devices_id` (`devices_id`),
  ADD KEY `devices_id_2` (`devices_id`);
--
-- Indexes for table `devices_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_type`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `devices_st_id` (`devices_st_id`);
--
-- Indexes for table `statuses`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `device_id` (`device_id`);
--
-- Indexes for table `statuses_chekid`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses_chekid`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `status_id` (`status_id`);
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `devices`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=48;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `devices_atribut`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_atribut`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `devices_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_type`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=40;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `statuses`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=40;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `statuses_chekid`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses_chekid`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=25;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--
--
-- Constraints for table `devices_atribut`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_atribut`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `s2` FOREIGN KEY (`devices_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`);
--
-- Constraints for table `devices_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `devices_type`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `s1` FOREIGN KEY (`devices_st_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`);
--
-- Constraints for table `statuses`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `s3` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`);
--
-- Constraints for table `statuses_chekid`
--
ALTER TABLE `statuses_chekid`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `s4` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`);
COMMIT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**

> SELECT *FROM `devices`inner JOIN `devices_atribut`  ON `devices`.id =
>   `devices_atribut`.`devices_id`inner JOIN `statuses` ON `devices`.id =
>   `statuses`.`devices_id`  inner JOIN `statuses_chekid` ON `statuses`.id
>   = `statuses_chekid`.`status_id`inner JOIN `devices_type` ON `devices`.id = `devices_type`.devices_id;"

**
**

Answer (score 0):

что-то такое.

```
SELECT *
FROM `devices`
LEFT JOIN `devices_atribut` 
  ON `devices`.id = `devices_atribut`.`devices_id`
LEFT JOIN `statuses` 
  ON `devices`.id = `statuses`.`devices_id`  
LEFT JOIN `statuses_chekid` 
  ON `statuses`.id = `statuses_chekid`.`status_id`
LEFT JOIN `devices_type` 
  ON `devices`.id = `devices_type`.devices_st_id
```

Comment: ИЗВЕНИТЕ но я получаю ошибку      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `devices`.id = `statuses`.`devices_id`  LEFT JOIN `statuses_chekid` ON   ON `' at line 1'

Comment: @MherBalayan, замените `ON   ON` на одинарный `ON`

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'statuses.devices_id' in 'on clause''
не могу понять,почему?

Comment: У вас в таблице `statuses` поле называется `device_id`, а не `devices_id`